# How can I get class where argument from?

Tags: java, selenium

How can I get class where argument is from?

I need to return Page.class from Utils.getClass.

Is it possible?

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class classOfField = Utils.getClassOfField(Page.LOCATOR);
  }
}

public class Page {
  public static final By LOCATOR = By.xpath("foo");

}

public class Utils {

  public static Class getClassOfField(By locator) {
    // I need to return Page.class
  }
}
```

Comment: Note you are passing an object, not a field. An object can be referenced by any number of fields, and those fields can belong to any number of classes. It could even be referenced by zero fields if you only assign the object to local variables. So, even if this were possible given your current setup, how would you guarantee that you return the "correct" class?

Comment: Understand you. Thx for help

Comment: What exactly would you like to get? Since you're passing `By` to the method then the class would be extensions of `By`. Can you explain what would that returned class then be used for?